# About Ethereum Chain Gas Price and Metamask Transactions

Tags: transactions, blockchain, wallets

I send eth to my wallet from Binance and it receive but after that strange transaction has been executed and withdrawal my eth is this a scam or official thing？？
[image: transaction image]

Transactions I made ↓

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x20b8a477cb6a0732a44edc6b19aa756e5a3e913f9dfc89e66fb4a684dbc40844

unknown transaction　↓

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x262e2f877fcc2fc1384a0d1efa3a76827dc8babd7775f7e6d2c97e089add4c36

who is this guy? official guy? scam guy?　↓

https://etherscan.io/address/0x752b133f3625a310d0442ca760b49af4029fce89

why this guy take so much gas price??　↓

https://etherscan.io/address/0xfeebabe6b0418ec13b30aadf129f5dcdd4f70cea

Comment: How did you generate that address? From the patter it seems the private key or mnemonic was compromised. Unfortunately there's not much you could do. Most of the ether was burned as transaction fees and only 666wei were sent to the hacker wallet.

Comment: Thank you for comment
why this guy withdrawal 666wei form everyone？
is it because unnotice？
https://etherscan.io/address/0x752b133f3625a310d0442ca760b49af4029fce89

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6d0cbd7ee555b8996dd238fe62866dcafdd13b7cf46a160f376fcb2aa7d919e4

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x60a5aae98ea003489cc1eb2a5502b495dafdc7308cbac13e0ec4201786378d37

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x425f72571e33115c80ebde921e484bca14f8bbe0441076e53be80f840e523d03

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x03cfa19fd701bf07b69a31515753274507877550097f7a6710108991acbc69fd

and other transaction gas fee is lower than my own

Comment: I've no idea why anyone will do something like that. Perhaps, they are hackers competing with each other.

Comment: I have same problem. I also send ETH to my metamask wallet, and scammer address: 0x752b133f3625a310d0442ca760b49af4029fce89 , automaticaly transfered ETH from my wallet.